# Conjugacy in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

How can I determine whether $A_1,A_2\in GL(n,\mathbb Z)$ conjugate in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$ and if they are, how can I find a $P\in GL(n,\mathbb Z)$ for which $A_2 = P^{-1}.A_1.P$ ?

In $GL(n,\mathbb Q)$ one could achieve this by checking if the Frobenius normal forms (FNF) are equal and if they are

$\quad\quad FNF_2 = FNF_1$

$\Leftrightarrow P_2^{-1}.A_2.P_2=P_1^{-1}.A_1.P_1$

$\Leftrightarrow A_2=M^{-1}.A_1.M\quad\quad\quad M=P_1.P_2^{-1}$

I found an [algorithm](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/32/37/05/PDF/Ozello.Patrick_1987_these.pdf) which gives the FNF of a matrix with P a matrix of integers. Is there an way of performing subsequent elementary similarity transformations on $P_i$ (and hence also on $P_i^{-1}$) until $P_i\in GL(n,\mathbb Z)$ while also checking whether it is even possible to arrive at such a $P_i$?

Comment: Doesn't the Smith normal form do it?  

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Comment: See Alex Eskin's answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69578/what-invariants-of-a-matrix-or-representation-can-be-used-to-find-its-gln-z-con/69587#69587


Comment: @Jose: I don't think the SNF does it, it allows multiplication by different (and unrelated) invertible matrices from the left and the right, and in any case is mostly trivial for $GL(N, \mathbb{Z}),$ since recall that the determinant is $\pm 1$ in $(GL(N, \mathbb{Z}),$ and so the elementary divisors are also $\pm 1.$

Comment: @Mark:Yes, Eskin's answer is the short form of Chris Godsil's question I allude to in my answer...

Comment: @Jose: I believe the SNF, just as the FNF, can be used for checking similarity in $GL(n,\mathbb Q)$ but not in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @Mark: I believe this is the Latimer-MacDuffee theorem? This can be applied when the two matrices have the same irreducible characteristic polynomial. Can this be extended to matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$? And if it can, how does it allow me to retrieve similarity transform M (see question)?

Comment: This is to elaborate on Mark's comment. I think we are indeed after forms of the Latimer-MacDuffee theorem. A couple of months ago, Mark pointed out to me a nice set of notes by Keith Conrad:
http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf
containing helpful references to papers by Taussky (1949) and Wallace (1984).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The Conjugacy Problem in $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.06190) by Eick, Hofmann and O'Brien gives an algorithm for solving this problem, which has been implemented in Magma.

Comment: more practical than what?

Comment: @YCor More practical than Grunewald's algorithm - but that makes no claims to be practical, so perhaps one should miss out the "more",

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I needed. Thanks @David Roe.

Comment: FYI an application of that problem is determining what space group is described by a given set of symmetry operations (we're talking about the Euclidean group and crystal symmetries in the domain of crystallography). The authors are active in this domain so no coincidence.

Answer (score 11):

This is the conjugacy problem for ${\mathop{\rm GL}}(n,\mathbb Z)$.  It was solved by Fritz Grunewald in the paper "Solution of the conjugacy problem in certain arithmetic groups" and also by R.A. Sarkisjan in "The conjugacy problem for collections of integral matrices".  See MathSciNet for reviews of these papers.

Comment: A good reference, but Grunewald's solution is not effective (as he himself points out in
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.3011
)

Comment: @Sam: Your answer is misleading. Sarkisjan (and independently Grunewald-Segal) solved the much harder problem of multiple conjugacy. 

Comment: @Mark: in the end, this is exactly what I need. But isn't that just an extension of the similarity-of-two-matrices-problem? Try all pairs of matrices, one from each set (or group in my case). If you find a pair that conjugates in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$, you can check if the groups conjugate by the same similarity transform P. If you can't find such P or if you can't find conjugate pairs at all, then the two groups don't conjugate. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Wox - Sarkisjan solves the following problem: Given two lists of matrices $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is there a single matrix $P$ so that for all $i$, $P A_i P^{-1} = B_i$?  This answers your question, because you can take $n = 1$.  Note, however, that the $n=1$ case does not solve the $n > 1$ case.  This is because the conjugating matrix $P$ need not be unique. 

Comment: Wox - also, if you are interested in infinite subgroups generated by more than one element, then checking conjugacy between a finite set of matrices is not going to be enough.

Comment: @HW: I only need to consider finite subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @Wox: Simultaneous conjugacy is much harder than simple conjugacy because the centralizer of a matrix may be infinite, so if you do what you suggest you need to check infinitely many matrices. In fact of course neither Grunewald-Segal nor Sarkisjan do that. They prove a version of the Hasse local-to-global principle (look at their papers!). Note that solvability of simultaneous conjugacy implies solvability of isomorphism problem for nilpotent (even virtually polycyclic) groups and for commutative semigroups. Both problems are very difficult. 

Answer (score 3):

See the below question (there are no answers, but the question is useful):
[Ideal classes and integral similarity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72213/ideal-classes-and-integral-similarity)

and also the following for a related question:

[symmetric integer matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70528/symmetric-integer-matrices)